# How to change inherited or included public methods to private

Tags: ruby

It might exist, but I've not been able to find an answer to this question via Google or on Stack Overflow.

I want to change the access status of a subset, or all inherited, or included from a module, public methods to private or protected.  Is this possible and how would I do that?  Just to try to make sure this is clear, an example:

```
class X
public
  def foo
    puts "I am foo"
  end
end

class Y < X
  <magic-phrase-to-make-foo-private>
  #...
end

x = X.new
x.foo # ("I am foo")
y = Y.new
y.foo # (Kablam!)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can say that foo is a private method by using the `private :method_name` syntax:

```rb
class X
public
  def foo
    puts "I am foo"
  end
end

class Y < X
  private :foo
end

x = X.new
x.foo # ("I am foo")
y = Y.new
y.foo # NoMethodError (private method `foo' called for #<Y:0x00007fe1e210bc58>)
```

Comment: To demonstrate without creating instances: `X.private_instance_methods.include?(:foo) #=> false; Y.private_instance_methods.include?(:foo) #=> true`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I used the following construct to extend your solution to make all methods inherited from a class or included from a module private:  <br/>`X.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
      if X.public_method_defined?(m, false) then
        private m
      end
    end`<br/>Unfortunately, although this always works in my test toy program, in my real project it sometimes fails (no "private method..." error).  I suspect a compiler bug - but that's another topic.  But at least it makes my code more self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, visibility of methods is changed by using the methods [`Module#private`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-private), [`Module#protected`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-protected), and [`Module#public`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-public). All you need to do is

```rb
private :foo
```